# Which verbs can be used with possessive pronouns?

Tags: gerunds, possessives, dictionaries

The *OALD* says "some verbs can be used with both a noun phrase and an 'ing phrase'. The frame for this is *<somebody>/<something> doing <something>*. and,

**(1)** the noun phrase can be the object of main verb.  (e.g. *I watched **him** running*)  or 
**(2)** the noun phrase and gerund together can be the object. (e.g. *I hate **him joking***) here, *him* can be replaced with possessive pronoun *his* (*I [hate](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hate_1) **his joking***)."

Further, the dictionary says "where the possessive pronoun is used is shown in the dictionary entry"

but in the dictionary entry, I can't see any symbol used to show the verbs which take possessive pronoun before gerunds.

My questions is:
How do we identify the **verbs**, which the only noun phrase can be the object of main verb and the noun phrase and gerund together can be the object of verb?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is an example of the so-called complex-object.There is no gerund here, running is participle I. In complex object we can use either the infinitive or participle I. So, your sentence can be rephrased: I watched him run ( bare infinitive in this case as to watch is a verb of physical perception) as for the second sentence, it' not complex-object (there are two separate objects, one of which is expressed by a gerund). In complex- object we can use only object pronouns, it's a rule. In the second sentence a possessive pronoun is possible, but it' s seldom used, I' d say it's semi- correct. So, always use object pronouns) and find more information about complex-object